# I want to implement Search in the website in PHP

Tags: php

Basically i want to implement Search in the website,and the issue is that.

In the page that i implement the search in which information that is displayed on the page that will fetch from the database and,its depend on the ID that was come from the previous page.And that is perfectelly working.But when i am click on the search button, then page is again load and ID that come on the URL that vanised and errror is display where i fetch the data from database because ID is not getting.

Please help me out friends.And i am try to explain my problem.

Comment: Any query related to question pls ask me

Comment: And the code? Do you think that we are wizards, or something else?

Comment: `$_SESSION() = $ID;` - [php.net/session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the error displaying ? Or can you post some code ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply friends,And error i already mention in the question.

Comment: That when i click on the search button the page is reload then the ID that i get from the url is vanished,And where i fired a query of fetching the information from database that show the error.       


Notice: Undefined index: search in D:\WebFAQ\faq.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\WebFAQ\faq.php on line 183


Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\WebFAQ\faq.php on line 187
0 results/faq.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: search in D:\WebFAQ\faq.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\WebFAQ\faq.php on line 183

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\WebFAQ\faq.php on line 187
0 results/faq.php

Comment: Unless you decide to post some code (including line #183), we cant help you son. Its something wrong with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all friend's that view my question.

Now i am getting my solution.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id1 ?>">
```

//Here hidden field is used for the storing the ID that come from the URL.

```
$searchText = NULL;   //this variable is used for the Search input box.
$id1 = NULL;          //this variable used for the passing in query.
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_GET['search'];
    $searchText = $_POST['search'];
}

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{   
   $id1 = $_POST['id'];    
}
```

Thanks friends to all for support me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form Element for the search, you have to put all that incoming values, like id and page into hidden fields in that form,
so the next page, processing the search, will have that information.

Comment: Thanks for reply Wolfgang Blessen. But every time ID that come from the previous page that will change every time.

Comment: And every page is linked to each other.And result will depand on the ID that got form the previous paga its FAQ website.